# how to display floating window with transparent images (actionable) as in this angry bird demo video.

Tags: android

I was looking android version of angry bird demo at http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=UnoiNhufRfg . At 1:03 min (elapsed time) in demo video, I see screen with wallpaper set to it in background & in the middle part of screen, a strip with transparent images (actionable) are displayed which can float left/right when we flick over it. Commands like Back at bottom-left corner, on other part of screen are also actionable at the same time. I have to develop a app which has similar requirement.
Can someone please suggest how to achieve this in android?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can use horizontal scroll view for this. You can add multiple layouts(as you can see in demo video, they are selectable). When you click on one of them, it performs certain action or so. You can make background of HSV as transparent and you can use margin to give space between the clickable views/controls. This is just a basic idea in my mind.